# Tkinter and PIL error

Tags: python, python-2.7, tkinter

I am trying to get a .gif animation to work next to a picture with buttons on it. but i seem to be having a issue, I am importing these modules 
"import Tkinter" and "from PIL import Image, ImageTk, ImageSequence"
But, as soon as I make "import Tkinter"---"from Tkinter import *" 
It says Tkinter is not defined, I have searched.. and searched.... and I cannot for the death of me find a solution.
I have to use "from Tkinter import *" because I don't know where to find the spesifics for a substetute for " * " I also need to use "Label", "bg" and "relief"
here is my code:

```
    import Tkinter
from PIL import Image, ImageTk, ImageSequence

class App:
    def __init__(self, parent):
        self.parent = parent
        self.canvas = Tkinter.Canvas(parent, width = 400, height = 500)
        self.canvas.pack()
        self.sequence = [ImageTk.PhotoImage(img)
                         for img in ImageSequence.Iterator(
                            Image.open(
                            r'C:\Users\Damian\Pictures\Gif folder\Originals\Bunnychan.gif'))]
        self.image = self.canvas.create_image(200,200, image=self.sequence[0])
        self.animating = True
        self.animate(0)
    def animate(self, counter):
        self.canvas.itemconfig(self.image, image=self.sequence[counter])
        if not self.animating:
            return
        self.parent.after(33, lambda: self.animate((counter+2) % len(self.sequence)))

root = Tkinter.Tk()
root.title('App')
app = App(root)
root.mainloop()
```

I have another piece that I am going to merge with this code:

```
import webbrowser
from Tkinter import *
from PIL import ImageTk,Image

Url1 = 'https://www.nedbank.co.za'
Url2 = 'https://www.facebook.com'

def openUrl1():
        webbrowser.open(Url1, 2)

def openUrl2():
        webbrowser.open(Url2, 2)

root = Tk()
root.title('App')
root.minsize(width = 400, height = 400)
root.maxsize(width = 400, height = 400)
image = Image.open("C:\\Users\\Damian\\Pictures\\Lores.png")
photo = ImageTk.PhotoImage(image)
label = Label(image = photo)
label.image = photo
label.place(x = 0, y = 0)

color1 = 'white'
button1 = Button(
            text = color1,
            bg = color1,
            relief = "raised",
            width = 220,
            height = 85,
            command = openUrl1
)
Original = Image.open("C:\\Users\\Damian\\Pictures\\NedbankLogoNew.png")
im_pm = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Original)
button1.config(image = im_pm)
button1.place(x = 0, y = 0)
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Why are you trying to change the `import Tkinter` to `from Tkinter import *`? The first is the preferred way. To just get the items you need, you could write something like `from Tkinter import Label, bg, relief`.

Comment: I imported "Label" that seems to import my picture now, thanks! just need to see if bg and others work... because I can't import bg and relief so far...

Comment: Thanks a bunch! everything working just fine.

Comment: Great, that's good to hear. You can see what symbolic constants `Tkinter` defines by looking at the `PythonXX/Lib/lib-tk/Tkconstants.py` file on your system. You'll find that most are just lowercase versions of the contant's name: i.e. `TOP='top'`. Note too that they're all `UPPERCASE` names.

Answer (score 0):

The recommended way to import tkinter is this:

```
import Tkinter as tk
```

Once you do that, you use tkinter as you normally would, but you need to prepend `tk.` to all of the widgets and constants. You can do `import Tkinter`, of course, but that means you have to prefix everything with `Tkinter.` which is a bit too wordy IMO.

For example:

```
import Tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()
label = tk.Label(root, relief=tk.RAISED)
...
```

Personally I don't recommend using the constants. You can just use a string (eg: `relief="raised"`, `sticky="nsew"`, etc.), which gives exactly the same results.